# Where is the "system defined file location" that a BAM FILE alert is delivered to?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-bam

Where is the "system defined file location" that a BAM FILE alert is delivered to?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560773.aspx) mentions ... *"a system-defined file location for a transport method of file"* but I can't find any details on where that exactly is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During BizTalk configuration ...

```
BAM Alerts File Location: 
Type the name of the network share that will be used to store the BAM alerts.
Note: You must manually create this share before BAM alerts can store the files.
```

Please refer to the below MSDN link,
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546832.aspx)

Comment: It's better to put the details in the response, rather than just a link

Answer (score 1):

By default, it's set to ...

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\BAM\alerts
```